# TOR with python stem (basic) - 'tor' not in PATH

Tags: python, python-3.x, tor, system-paths

I'm trying to get an .onion website's content to python, a little research showed that '[stem](https://stem.torproject.org/faq.html#how-do-i-connect-to-tor)' 
and as i am running this [tutorial script](https://stem.torproject.org/tutorials/to_russia_with_love.html), or more specifically, when i'm trying to use **stem.process.launch_tor_with_config**, i get this error:

> 'tor' isn't available on your system. Maybe it's not in your PATH?

I supposed to have some sort of tor process installed, I got the tor browser bundle and put the /Tor library (with the tor.exe) in it in my path, and it's not helping...
Obviously I'm  missing something VERY BASIC, please advise....

Many thanks...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same issue on my Mac. Try specifying exactly where the tor file is located to the tor_cmd parameter:

```
tor_process = stem.process.launch_tor_with_config(
    tor_cmd = '/Applications/TorBrowser.app/Tor/tor.real',
    config = { SocksPort': str(SOCKS_PORT),
               'ExitNodes': '{ru}',},
    init_msg_handler = print_bootstrap_lines,
)
```

Comment: there it is:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25114593/stem-as-python-tor-client-stuck-on-loading-descriptors

Comment: @abpai I am running into the same problem. But I can't find the tor.real file anywhere. I am running Ubuntu 14.04 on VirtualBox and there's a file known as tor in the `/tor-browser_en-US/Browser/TorBrowser/Tor` folder but I am not sure if its the same one since when I add this path, it gives an error. Could you please help?

Comment: Nowadays (in _MacOs Sierra_) the `tor_cmd` right path is: `/Applications/TorBrowser.app/Contents/MacOS/Tor/tor.real`